# Echo all of the ids as one id and get lines from it in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm working on Roblox Friends API https://friends.roblox.com/v1/users/261/friends
Im trying to echo all of the Ids as $ids and echo it out like this $ids[2], Which is the third ID

```
<?php
$id = "261";
$ch = file_get_contents('https://friends.roblox.com/v1/users/'.$id.'/friends');

$data = json_decode($ch);

foreach ($data->id as $ids){
    echo $ids[1];
}
?>
```

This code doesn't work. Seems I cannot find an solution anywhere.
I want it to echo out the first id.

Comment: There is no `$data->id`. If you are unsure what the structure of the decoded JSON actually is, then make a `var_dump($data);`.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/4W2gM2x7 this is the result @CBroe

Comment: You don't need to show me, I wanted _you_ to go have a proper look at it, and try to _understand_ how it is actually structured.

Comment: I cannot understand it. Could you help me out?

Comment: @CBroe Hello? U there?

Comment: What meant to do was use `$id->id` inside your loop instead of `$id[1]` because the resulting array contains objects and not integers that you can print.

Comment: Hmm what? do you mean

Comment: I don't understand can you give me the working code?

Comment: First of all, the JSON contains an object - so you should probably decode it with the second parameter of json_decode set to true, so that you get an associative array instead. Then, add `<pre>` before the var_dump output, so that you don't get it all in one line, but can actually see the structure. And if it is still unclear to you now, how to get to the elements you are interested in - then maybe it would be time for you to stick your nose into some beginner tutorials at this point ...?

Comment: alright. I figured it out Thanks

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to include all the important details, such as precisely what the phrase "this code doesn't work" means (was there an error? what error? in what way did it not work?), as well as some information about what research you have already done, etc., what specific thing you want to know, etc. Remember Stack Overflow is for answering questions, not free contracting (doing a job for someone).

Comment: If you have been able to answer your own question, it is encouraged to [post an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that other people can benefit, and you can accept your own answer after 48 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use next piece of code:

```
<?php
$id = "261";
$ch = file_get_contents('https://friends.roblox.com/v1/users/'.$id.'/friends');

$data = json_decode($ch)->data;

foreach ($data as $d){
    echo $d->id . PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Test PHP json_decode online](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php8/fc73b04e30f1874e9fc31fc455694e0b/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
$ch = file_get_contents('https://friends.roblox.com/v1/users/261/friends');
//set to TRUE if you want to use the result as associative array
$data = json_decode($ch, true)['data'];
//simple loop over your data
foreach($data as $datum) {
    echo $datum['id'] . "<br>";
}
//or if you need to keep only the id of each item 
$ids = array_column($data, 'id');
foreach($ids as $id) {
    echo $id . "<br>";
}
```